# Accessing swift classess

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way to access the variable in a class using a String? E.g. I have the following struct `Person.swift`:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String?
    let id: String?
}
```

Can I access the variable `name` and change the variable using a some sort of string-reflection method, like Java, instead of a call to the `Person.name = ""` method?

Comment: Key value coding or subscripting?

Comment: https://github.com/bradhilton/SwiftKVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access props as strings using **KVC**

The only downside is It's originally from **Objects c** so you can not use **structs**, and your props have to be **Objective C dynamic types**:

```
  class Person: NSObject, Codable {
       @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
   }


   let person = Person.init()
   person.name = "Mat" // Name value "Mat"

   person.setValue("Josh", forKey: "name") // Name value "Josh"
```

Comment: @Devxln did this help you?